# Can the C++ Array class be passed as a parameter with variable size?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, parameters

I am aware that a regular, built-in array can be passed in to a function with variable sizes.  However, is there a good technique to be able to write a single function that takes an array class object reference, but the size can be variable?

Is there a template technique for doing this?  Or do we just use vectors instead?

Thanks!

~ G

UPDATE:
Clarification - I'm speaking of the `std::array` class in `<array>` library.  When you create an instance of the class, it has two template parameters:  `array<type, size>`.

Comment: Arrays have sizes that won't change after compiling. "_a single function that takes an array class object_" would perhaps be _writing_ the template for the function - but it'd be instantiated as just as many functions as you have arrays with different extents using that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am aware that a regular, built-in array can be passed in to a function with variable sizes.

No, it can't. It can only be passed in by-pointer or by-reference.  In the case of by-pointer, all size information is lost.  In the case of by-reference, the size has to be stated explicitly in the parameter itself as part of its type, thus you can't pass separate arrays of different sizes to the same function.

> However, is there a good technique to be able to write a single function that takes an array class object reference, but the size can be variable?

Yes, use a template for the size, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
void doSomething(T (&arr)[N])
{
    // use arr up to N elements as needed...
}
```

```cpp
int arr1[5];
doSomething(arr1);

char arr2[10];
doSomething(arr2);

...
```

**UPDATE**: in the case of `std::array`, the template approach still works, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
void doSomething(std::array<T, N> &arr) {
    // use arr up to N elements as needed...
}
```

```cpp
std::array<int, 5> arr1;
doSomething(arr1);

std::array<char, 10> arr2;
doSomething(arr2);

...
```

Comment: Remy - thanks for the response.  I was more speaking on a logical level of the built-in arrays.  Obviously, as you've indicated, an array can be passed in by and it doesn't carry size information.  The size could be passed along as a separate parameter, so that the contiguous memory can be properly divided.  However, I am asking about the <array> library's class, not the built-in arrays.

Comment: Remy - I played around with the templates and I see what you were saying now.  It works with the array class also.  Thanks a lot! - G

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a template technique for doing this?

Yes. The technique is: Use a template.

Example:

```
template<class Array>
void function(const Array&);
```

Note that templates are a compile time entities and the size cannot be variable at runtime.

> Or do we just use vectors instead?

For arrays with runtime bound: Yes.